# How frequently IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast receives in Google IAB v2

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have been implementing Google IAB v2 in my app. I read from Google IAB v2 documentation "**Google Play will continue sending IN_APP_NOTIFY messages for the transactions you have not confirmed.**" But in documentation it is not explained how frequently this broadcast will trigger if already I have not sent CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request.
You can see documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/api.html#figure2)

Actually I have not received multiple IN_APP_NOTIFY broadcast after successful "REQUEST_PURCHASE" request and I have not sent CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS request yet.

I want to know the time interval between second IN_APP_NOTIFY message after first time received or how much time I have to wait for next IN_APP_NOTIFY message or I have to do something extra to receives next IN_APP_NOTIFY messages?